# How to set 3D cursor orientation in Keymapping (in python)?

Tags: python, geometry

[image]

Hello!

I'm trying to set the orientation of the 3D cursor to "Geometry" in the keymapping preferences in Blender but having some difficulty. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to change the key map:

1. You can change the user keymapping at runtime (although i'm not quite sure what the advantage would be over using the UI):

   ```py
   bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs['Blender user'].keymaps['3D View'].keymap_items['view3d.cursor3d'].properties.orientation = 'GEOM'
   ```

   See docs for the operator properties: https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.cursor3d

   You need to call [bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=save%20user%20pref#bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref) to make this persistent, otherwise the change is discarded when closing Blender.
2. You can change the "factory default" by changing the properties in `<Blender install>/<version>/scripts/presets/keyconfig/keymap_data/blender_default.py`. I wouldn't recommend this unless you are actually planning to submit a patch.

```py
    # 3D cursor
    if params.cursor_tweak_event:
        items.extend([
            ("view3d.cursor3d", params.cursor_set_event, {"properties": [("orientation": 'GEOM')]}),
            ("transform.translate", params.cursor_tweak_event,
             {"properties": [("release_confirm", True), ("cursor_transform", True)]}),
        ])
    else:
        items.extend([
            ("view3d.cursor3d", params.cursor_set_event, {"properties": [("orientation": 'GEOM')]}
        ])
```